# What is this sans-serif font?

Tags: typography, font-identification

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNbs8.png]

Can anyone identify this font? I've tried on identifont and on WhatTheFont but I can't find anything. It's the slanted 'e' and the ampersand that really stump me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks a lot like ITC Kabel, but the ampersand does look different. Maybe this helps for your further search..

Comment: Kabel seems to be a perfect match apart from the ampersand. It could be from a different font. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free service to identify the font: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/. It recognise fonts from images and URLs.

Answer (score -1):

Your best resource to identify fonts is http://typophile.com. There is an entire forum specifically for identifying typefaces from the Type Design community.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Typophile is definitely a good resource to identify fonts; [we do refer people to it](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is [referenced occasionally](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=typophile). Your post doesn't really answer the question; it's merely an invitation to another site and thus might end up being flagged, especially when it follows another post that seems to have answered the question and when both of your answers so far link out to Typophile. Hope you stick around and answer more questions here though!

Comment: Completely understandable. Hopefully I didn't come across as spam but as others might likely visit this question, it is a relevant resource for them to be aware of.

Comment: @ChrisBurton I edited your other answer because the link was unrelated to the question. This one looks valid to me, but as Brendan mentions, please don't repeat the invite unless it's relevant.

Answer (score -1):

The closest i have found is "Caviar dreams" , that has the slanted e, but the ampersand is slightly different.

https://www.dafont.com/caviar-dreams.font?text=Poventud+%26+Santo&back=theme